# Does every OAuth2.0 API support "sign-in with" functionality?

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, 23andme-api

Most of my users already use an service called 23andMe, [which supports OAuth2.0](https://api.23andme.com/docs/authentication/).

I want to let my users ***register for my app*** by authenticating with this service. This should be easy since I can pull their email address over api once they authenticate.

I want to ***continually pull data*** from this service on behalf of my user. This should be doable using a job that uses their refresh token.

I want to let my users ***sign-in to my app*** by authenticating with this service. This is the part I'm struggling with.

*Does the OAuth-capable API in question need to offer special methods in order to let users login using their service?*

*Or can I achieve "login with" functionality using any OAuth-capable API?*

*When a user clicks "login with X," do I have to check my db for a user with an email that matches their "X" email? Or is there an easier way?*

> I see that Google's API has a [`GoogleAuth` object that handle session
>   functionality](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#authentication)

Comment: "When a user clicks "login with X," do I have to check my db for a user with an email that matches their "X" email?" - sounds about right

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu hmm well i would still have to ask for their password, and i would someone have to access their browser client cache or whatever to find out their username with that service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 23andMe developer:

> Our login does not behave like facebook/twitter/google auth. It is
>   meant to allow you as a developer to request access to a 23andMe
>   customers data as detailed
>   https://api.23andme.com/docs/authentication/